# How to use HttpClient

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm currently trying to get some data via a 'uri' using the following code in java:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null){
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            callString = stream.toString();
            return callString;
        }
```

However this isn't working. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: "This isn't working" isn't particularly helpful information. What happens instead? What happens not? Do you get any exceptions? Please share them.

Comment: This is currently in a try catch block and the catch is fired. URI is http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print out the input stream like that... instead, do something like this:-

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
```

The printout looks like this:-

```
1994-02-02,84.75,85.50,84.00,84.00,40924800,2.09
1994-02-01,85.00,85.75,84.50,85.12,44003200,2.12
1994-01-31,85.25,85.87,84.75,85.12,62566400,2.12
1994-01-28,84.50,85.50,84.25,84.87,41875200,2.11
1994-01-27,84.00,84.75,83.25,84.25,51129600,2.10
1994-01-26,85.00,85.00,84.00,84.25,50489600,2.10
1994-01-25,85.25,85.37,84.00,85.12,70361600,2.12
...
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working in my activity. Is there another way to parse the response?

Answer (score 0):

Its a total guess but shouldn't it be:

```
String uri = "ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT"

HttpData data = HttpRequest.get(uri);
System.out.println(data.content);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to download a file and getEntity is used get an object for a type you have specified. IMHO this wont work.

You need to code which will actually read the response stream and read contents out of it...

What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to download this file then parse it so that I can get the share price of MSFT into an array.

Answer (score 0):

To read the resulting entity to a String use [`EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) or  [`EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity, String)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity,%20java.lang.String%29) if you know the character set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting NetworkOnMainThreadException then that means you are calling client.execute(get); on the main thread which is an exception thrown on Honeycomb and higher.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html for details.  The solution is to run this in a new thread.